# Convert OpenIE triplet to N-Triplet (NT)

Tags: java, nlp, rdf, owl

I downloaded and used OpenIE4.1 jar file (downloadable from http://knowitall.github.io/openie/) to process some free text documents and produced triplet-like outputs along with the text and confidence score, for instance,

```
The rail launchers  are conceptually similar to the underslung SM-1
0.93 (The rail launchers; are; conceptually similar to the underslung SM-1)
```

I wrote a java parser to extract OpenIE triplets which confidence score is >= 0.85 and
need to know the way to convert it to N-triplet (NT), format look like.

Not sure if I need to be familiar with the ontology that I'm trying to map to.

Comment: **I'm not sure if I first need to get familiar with the ontology that I'm trying to map to.**  You do, just like you'd need to be familiar with a programming language or API that you use, etc.  Even if, for some reason, *you* don't need to get familiar with it, you'll need to become familiar enough with it to explain to *us* what the output is supposed to look like.  The N-Triples format is very simple:  it's just `subject predicate object .` on each line.  The sample you've shown has a blank node as the subject, rdf:type as the predicate, and the string "SM-1" as the object.  That's…

Comment: …just telling us that that "there's something with type "SM-1".  That certainly isn't a translation of the triple that you've got.  We need more information.

Comment: After discussion with my colleagues, this is what I should do to create N-Triplet(NT): 1. Create a blank node identifier for each distinct :subject in the file (call it node_s) 2. Create a blank node identifier for each distinct :object in the file (call it node_o) 3. Define a URI for each distinct predicate 4. Create these triples:

Comment: a.  node_s              rdf:type                <http://mypage.org/vocab#Corpus>
b.  node_s              dc:title                 “The rail launchers”
c.  node_s              dc:source            “Sample File”
d.  node_s              rdf:predicate      <http://mypage.org/vocab#are>
e.  http://mypage.org/vocab#are    rdfs:label             “are”  
f.  node_s              rdf:object          node_o
g.  node_o              rdf:type                <http://mypage.org/vocab#Corpus>
h.  node_o              dc:title                 “conceptually similar to the underslung SM-1”

Comment: I was told that Jena, OpenRDF or Protoge API has the capability build in to create blank node and write RDF triplets. Still need guidance how to create one, what is the input format into the API.

Comment: I see that you posted that as an answer.  It's quite alright to answer your own question on Stack Overflow.  I think that you should undelete the answer and mark it as accepted.  How to generate that RDF using Jena is a really a different question, and you could ask it as a separate question.  I think there are some issues with the particular encoding that you've proposed though;  some of the triples don't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: The N-triplet format is recommended by my colleague. Yes - I agree with you that some tiplets don't make sense. Any other recommendation? Will post a separate Jean related question.

Comment: The particular serialization format of the RDF doesn't really matter, but N-Triples is easy to write (one triple per line), as is Turtle, which is also more human readable.  What I don't understand about the is some of the nodes.  So there's a node s with title "The rail launchers" and source "Sample File".  That makes sense to me, but then you also say that "s is a (rdf:type) Corpus".  That doesn't make as much sense to me.  And the rdfs:predicate, rdf:object properties are supposed to be used for reifying triples.  That doesn't seem to be what's happening here.

Comment: How can I fix to make sense of them, particularly predicate and object?

Answer (score 1):

After discussion with my colleagues. This is what I should do to create N-Triplet(NT) and Detailed Java codes can be found in another Question: [Use RDF API (Jena, OpenRDF or Protege) to convert OpenIE outputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897405/use-rdf-api-jena-openrdf-or-protege-to-convert-openie-outputs)

1. Create a blank node identifier for each distinct :subject in the file (call it node_s)
2. Create a blank node identifier for each distinct :object in the file (call it node_o)
3. Define a URI for each distinct predicate
4. Create these triples:

   ```
   1.  node_s              rdf:type                <http://mypage.org/vocab#Corpus>
   2.  node_s              dc:title                 “The rail launchers”
   3.  node_s              dc:source            “Sample File”
   4.  node_s              rdf:predicate      <http://mypage.org/vocab#are>
   5.  node_o              rdf:type                <http://mypage.org/vocab#Corpus>
   6.  node_o              dc:title                 “conceptually similar to the underslung SM-1”
   ```

Comment: Sorry that the answer has been repeated on comments above.