# Use RDF API (Jena, OpenRDF or Protege) to convert OpenIE outputs

Tags: nlp, rdf, jena, protege, sesame

I was recommended to use one of the APIs (Jena, OpenRDF or Protege) to convert the outputs that I generated from OpenIE4.1 jar file (downloadable from http://knowitall.github.io/openie/). The following is the sample OpenIE4.1 output format: confidence score followed by subject, predicate, object triplet

```
    The rail launchers are conceptually similar to the underslung SM-1
    0.93 (The rail launchers; are; conceptually similar to the underslung SM-1)
```

I planned to produce triples that follow this pattern from above output (in fact, hundreds of above outputs have been generated by processing a sets of free text documents, only confidence score greater than certain value will be processed):

Given

```
    subject: The rail launchers
    predicate: are
    object: conceptually similar to the underslung SM-1
```

(confidence score is ignored)

1. Create a blank node identifier for each distinct :subject in the file (let’s call it bnode_s)
2. Create a blank node identifier for each distinct :object in the file (let’s call it bnode_o)
3. Define a URI for each distinct predicate

BTW, I do have outputs that produce more than triplets, for instance
         John gave Mary a birthday gift
         (John; gave; Mary; a birthday gift)
which is more complicated to product RDF triplet.

However, I'm not familiar with any of the API mentioned above and don't know the input format that API may take.

Comment: I saw your earlier question, but there's not enough in this one to be self contained.  E.g., you say that you want to " Create a blank node identifier for each distinct :subject in the file", but you haven't said what the a "distinct :subject in the file" is.  Since you're asking how to generate some specific output using one of these libraries, generate some sample output first.  E.g., what's the RDF that should be generated for the sentence you've shown us? Is (…;…;…) supposed to map to a triple, or is that just a fortunate accident of this particular data?

Comment: Do you want output more or less like http://pastebin.com/sFwfqLFM?

Comment: I meant RDF that should be generated for the sentence in above example.

Comment: Yes, I understand that you want to generate RDF.  What I mean is that you show us "0.93 (The rail launchers; are; conceptually similar to the underslung SM-1)" and give us the instruction "Create a blank node identifier for each distinct :subject in the file" but you don't tell us what "a subject in the file" is.   Is "conceptually similar to the underslung SM-1" a subject in the file?  Is "The rail launchers" a subject is the file?  Is "0.93" a subject in the file?  It doesn't help to give us instructions without telling us what the words in the instructions mean.  We certainly guess…

Comment: that since you've given us something like (…;…;…), that the first part is a subject, the second is a predicate, and that the third is an object, but that's not guaranteed.  Could a more complex sentence produce something like (…;…;…;…;…)?  You need to tell us what you're showing us.

Comment: My question has been edited. It should clarify some of your comments

Comment: It clarifies some of them, although you haven't given instructions for what to do if the output has tuples that have more than three entries.

Comment: Any suggestion to handle tuples >= 3 entires?

Comment: Handling the >3 (just like the <3 cases) seems like a pretty straightforward n-ary relation (though you might move away from using rdf:{subject,predicate,object}).  See [Defining N-ary Relations on the Semantic Web](http://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-n-aryRelations/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
import org.apache.jena.riot.Lang;
import org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Property;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.URIref;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary.RDF;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary.RDFS;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary.XSD;

public class OpenIETripletConversionExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create the model and define some prefixes (for nice serialization in RDF/XML and TTL)
        Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        String NS = "http://stackoverflow.com/q/24897405/1281433/";
        model.setNsPrefix( "", NS );
        model.setNsPrefix( "rdf", RDF.getURI() );
        model.setNsPrefix( "xsd", XSD.getURI() );
        model.setNsPrefix( "rdfs", RDFS.getURI() );

        // Preserve the confidence level (optional).
        Property confidence = model.createProperty( NS+"confidence" ); 

        // Define some triplets to convert.
        Object[][] triplets = {
                { 0.57, "The quick brown fox", "jumped", "over the lazy dog." },
                { 0.93, "The rail launchers", "are", "conceptually similar to the underslung SM-1." }
        };

        // For each triplet, create a resource representing the sentence, as well as the subject, 
        // predicate, and object, and then add the triples to the model.
        for ( Object[] triplet : triplets )  {
            Resource statement = model.createResource();
            Resource subject = model.createResource().addProperty( RDFS.label, (String) triplet[1] );
            Property predicate = model.createProperty( NS+URIref.encode( (String) triplet[2] ));
            Resource object = model.createResource().addProperty( RDFS.label, (String) triplet[3] );

            statement.addLiteral( confidence, triplet[0] );
            statement.addProperty( RDF.subject, subject );
            statement.addProperty( RDF.predicate, predicate );
            statement.addProperty( RDF.object, object );
        }

        // Show the model in a few different formats.
        RDFDataMgr.write( System.out, model, Lang.TTL );
        RDFDataMgr.write( System.out, model, Lang.RDFXML );
        RDFDataMgr.write( System.out, model, Lang.NTRIPLES );
    }
}
```

```
@prefix :      <http://stackoverflow.com/q/24897405/1281433/> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

[ rdf:object     [ rdfs:label  "conceptually similar to the underslung SM-1." ] ;
  rdf:predicate  :are ;
  rdf:subject    [ rdfs:label  "The rail launchers" ] ;
  :confidence    "0.93"^^xsd:double
] .

[ rdf:object     [ rdfs:label  "over the lazy dog." ] ;
  rdf:predicate  :jumped ;
  rdf:subject    [ rdfs:label  "The quick brown fox" ] ;
  :confidence    "0.57"^^xsd:double
] .
```

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns="http://stackoverflow.com/q/24897405/1281433/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
  <rdf:Description>
    <rdf:object rdf:parseType="Resource">
      <rdfs:label>conceptually similar to the underslung SM-1.</rdfs:label>
    </rdf:object>
    <rdf:predicate rdf:resource="http://stackoverflow.com/q/24897405/1281433/are"/>
    <rdf:subject rdf:parseType="Resource">
      <rdfs:label>The rail launchers</rdfs:label>
    </rdf:subject>
    <confidence rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double"
    >0.93</confidence>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description>
    <rdf:object rdf:parseType="Resource">
      <rdfs:label>over the lazy dog.</rdfs:label>
    </rdf:object>
    <rdf:predicate rdf:resource="http://stackoverflow.com/q/24897405/1281433/jumped"/>
    <rdf:subject rdf:parseType="Resource">
      <rdfs:label>The quick brown fox</rdfs:label>
    </rdf:subject>
    <confidence rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double"
    >0.57</confidence>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

```
_:BX2D492663e1X3A1475ff7864cX3AX2D7ffe <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "The quick brown fox" .
_:BX2D492663e1X3A1475ff7864cX3AX2D7ffc <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#object> _:BX2D492663e1X3A1475ff7864cX3AX2D7ffa .
_:BX2D492663e1X3A1475ff7864cX3AX2D7ffc <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#predicate> <http://stackoverflow.com/q/24897405/1281433/are> .
_:BX2D492663e1X3A1475ff7864cX3AX2D7ffc <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#subject> _:BX2D492663e1X3A1475ff7864cX3AX2D7ffb .
_:BX2D492663e1X3A1475ff7864cX3AX2D7ffc <http://stackoverflow.com/q/24897405/1281433/confidence> "0.93"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double> .
_:BX2D492663e1X3A1475ff7864cX3AX2D7ffa <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "conceptually similar to the underslung SM-1." .
_:BX2D492663e1X3A1475ff7864cX3AX2D7fff <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#object> _:BX2D492663e1X3A1475ff7864cX3AX2D7ffd .
_:BX2D492663e1X3A1475ff7864cX3AX2D7fff <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#predicate> <http://stackoverflow.com/q/24897405/1281433/jumped> .
_:BX2D492663e1X3A1475ff7864cX3AX2D7fff <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#subject> _:BX2D492663e1X3A1475ff7864cX3AX2D7ffe .
_:BX2D492663e1X3A1475ff7864cX3AX2D7fff <http://stackoverflow.com/q/24897405/1281433/confidence> "0.57"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double> .
_:BX2D492663e1X3A1475ff7864cX3AX2D7ffd <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "over the lazy dog." .
_:BX2D492663e1X3A1475ff7864cX3AX2D7ffb <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "The rail launchers" .
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. What is the Jena API version you are using? 2.11.2?

Comment: Not sure offhand, but I expect that this will work with the latest version.

Comment: @HappyJubilee Why does the exact version matter, though?  Did you try this code and it didn't work? If so, what error problem did you have?

Comment: No worries. It was my current Eclipse not compatible with java 8. Has been fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness (since the OP asked about several APIs) I am repeating @Joshua Taylor's solution but using the OpenRDF Sesame API instead of Jena:

```java
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import org.openrdf.model.Model;
import org.openrdf.model.Resource;
import org.openrdf.model.URI;
import org.openrdf.model.ValueFactory;
import org.openrdf.model.impl.LinkedHashModel;
import org.openrdf.model.impl.ValueFactoryImpl;
import org.openrdf.model.util.Literals;
import org.openrdf.model.vocabulary.RDF;
import org.openrdf.model.vocabulary.RDFS;
import org.openrdf.model.vocabulary.XMLSchema;
import org.openrdf.rio.RDFFormat;
import org.openrdf.rio.RDFHandlerException;
import org.openrdf.rio.Rio;

public class OpenIETripletConversionExample {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, RDFHandlerException {
            // Create the model and define some prefixes (for nice serialization in RDF/XML and TTL)
            Model model = new LinkedHashModel();
            String NS = "http://stackoverflow.com/q/24897405/1281433/";
            model.setNamespace("rdf", RDF.NAMESPACE);
            model.setNamespace("rdfs", RDFS.NAMESPACE);
            model.setNamespace("xsd", XMLSchema.NAMESPACE);
            model.setNamespace("", NS);

            // Create a ValueFactory we can use to create resources and statements
            ValueFactory vf = ValueFactoryImpl.getInstance();

            // Preserve the confidence level (optional).
            URI confidence = vf.createURI(NS, "confidence"); 

            // Define some triplets to convert.
            Object[][] triplets = {
                    { 0.57, "The quick brown fox", "jumped", "over the lazy dog." },
                    { 0.93, "The rail launchers", "are", "conceptually similar to the underslung SM-1." }
            };

            // For each triplet, create a resource representing the sentence, as well as the subject, 
            // predicate, and object, and then add the triples to the model.
            for ( Object[] triplet : triplets )  {
                Resource sentence = vf.createBNode();
                Resource subject = vf.createBNode();
                URI predicate = vf.createURI(NS, URLEncoder.encode((String) triplet[2], "utf-8"));
                Resource object = vf.createBNode();

                model.add(subject, RDFS.LABEL, Literals.createLiteral(vf, triplet[1]));
                model.add(object, RDFS.LABEL, Literals.createLiteral(vf, (String)triplet[3]));

                model.add(sentence, confidence, Literals.createLiteral(vf, triplet[0]));
                model.add(sentence, RDF.SUBJECT, subject);
                model.add(sentence, RDF.PREDICATE, predicate);
                model.add(sentence, RDF.OBJECT, object);
            }

            // Show the model in a few different formats.
            Rio.write(model, System.out, RDFFormat.TURTLE);
            Rio.write(model, System.out, RDFFormat.RDFXML);
            Rio.write(model, System.out, RDFFormat.NTRIPLES);

        }
}
```